# Problem in running react-native code in my device

Tags: android, react-native

The code doesn't run in my device, please help...!

```
G:\React\blawblaW>react-native run-android
info JS server already running.
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat app:installDebug)...
```

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

```
G:\React\blawblaW\android\app\src\main\java\com\blawblaw\MainActivity.java:23: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
            ^
G:\React\blawblaW\android\app\src\main\java\com\blawblaw\MainActivity.java:26: error: class, interface, or enum expected
      protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
                ^
G:\React\blawblaW\android\app\src\main\java\com\blawblaw\MainActivity.java:28: error: class, interface, or enum expected
      }
      ^
G:\React\blawblaW\android\app\src\main\java\com\blawblaw\MainActivity.java:30: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  }
  ^
4 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
24 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 23 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: As the error says do you have emulator running.

Comment: yes I'm sure that my phone is connected

Comment: Can you open another console and run command `adb devices` and see if it lists your device there?

Comment: @blaz 
List of devices attached
ce041714519f6c990d      device
yes It shows my device

Comment: Run `adb unistall [package.name]` Replace package name with your package name for example com.test.app etc. It may have a previously installed version lying around somewhere.

Comment: @JRK it gives "adb: usage: unknown command unsitall" error.
what should I do after that?

Comment: Sorry was a typo "uninstall"

Comment: @JRK sorry nothing special happened \:

Answer (score 0):

Eject your app using react-native CLI. from your app root run this commands

```
react-native eject
```

and then link your package

```
react-native link
```

Ejecting app will reset your cache and other linked dependencies.